# Cómo quitar los 0 de la izquierda de un registro al momento de insertar

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola muy buenas comunidad, necesito insertar algunos registros, algunos vienen con 0 a la izquierda y debo eliminarlos. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
INSERT INTO `nombre_tabla`
(`numero`)
VALUES
(p_numero);
```

La consulta del procedimiento almacenado es sencilla, al momento de insertar algunos números vienen con 0 a la izquierda. ¿Cómo los podría quitar? ¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que la columna es de tipo string (varchar, etc) y debido a que no estas especificando que SGDB estas usando.

En SQL Server puedes usar LTRIM por ejemplo

```
INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (numero)
VALUES (LTRIM(p_numero));
```

Si usas MySQL

```
INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (numero)
VALUES (TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM p_numero));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta funciona a la perfección, estaba utilizando MySQL, saludos!!! :)